# What is modern take on the idea of wills?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Under wills I mean either Schopenhauer's *will to live* or Nietzsche's *will to power* or other wills like will to meaning and many more.

As I guess, their authors intended to explain human behaviour by them. Nietzsche, for example, argued that whatever humans do is to get power.

Personally, I feel that it's too simplistic. But what is the modern/contemporary approach on the topic?

Comment: This guess is indeed too simplistic, but I do not understand where you got it from. Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_power) is far more nuanced. And it gives interpretations by Freudists, Derrida and Deleuze, among others.

Comment: @Conifold Although I did not mean that the guess is too simplistic. And I read that article. I know what is the main thought there and still I can't say that strife for power is the main driving force in me. Other people are willing to sacrifice their own lives in some cases and there are nihilists out there that have no will to meaning.

Comment: That is not how it works... anywhere. Cheerful and self-sacrificing people are no more an objection to death and power drives than cold spells are an objection to global warming. Freud was particularly apt at explaining that, see [death drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_drive).

Comment: @Conifold Yeah, I am not denying there are wills. The idea, though, often is to place some will above others. As such, though, I find that approach problematic. One can argue that will to power is a byproduct of will to live. Or vice versa. But though there is death drive, as you said, which hardly is a byproduct of either. And thus I guess there might be theories solving these problems.

Comment: People mostly moved past the loose language of "wills", you can look at [neurology of drives and motives](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cognitive_Psychology_and_Cognitive_Neuroscience/Motivation_and_Emotion#About_Drives_and_Motives).

Comment: MEGILL, A.: "Prophets of Extremity: Neitzsche, Heidegger. Foucault, Derrida"   If my memory is correct, "Will"  is discussed in this book by Megill. The book can be found in many libraries. There is not a lot of discussion but it is discussed intelligently imo. Here is a link to a book review, sorry it does not appear to be free?  To me, your question is very important, good.

Comment: https://philpapers.org/rec/HARMAP-4